# what is the difference between Dolphin Browser HD and Mini versions?

Tags: dolphin-browser

I look at the [official Dolphin Browser page](http://www.dolphin-browser.com/), but I can't seem to find any differences, besides:

- Dolphin Browser Mini – Fast & Simple
- Dolphin Browser HD – Powerful & Elegant

In what sense is HD powerful or elegant?

In what sense is Mini simple?

What am I missing out on if I use Mini instead of HD?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used Dolphin HD for some time now, but every time I try to compare its features with Dolphin Mini I get frustrated, there is no clear documentation everywhere.

That said, Dolphin Mini is a version of the browser that is optimized for velocity and reduced resources use, so I came to the conclusion that Dolphin HD is the right path to go if you have a terminal with decent resources (700Mhz o more powerfull processor, 512Mb of RAM or More, 800x400 resolution, etc....) while the Mini version is here to that ones that do not have this kind of terminals or that prefer a more faster browser even at the cost of missing some features.

So with the two versions being free I choose Dolphin HD if the terminal is powerfull enough to allow you to maintain 3 or more tabs open an user flash.

Comment: Is there a possible correlation with Opera and Opera Mini?  Opera Mini is smaller and does most of its rendering on Opera's servers before sending a compressed, small-sized web page to your phone.  It is better for slower phones and for those with a limited data connection.  I don't know about Dolphin, but could it be the same kind of difference?

Comment: Opera Mini and Opera Mobile may have differences, since pre-webkit Opera uses its own rendering engine, Presto. They're not required to use the exact same code for both. However, Dolphin HD and Dolphin Mini use the provided version of Webkit that Android comes with. Rendering should be the same, although other characteristics of the browser may differ (how many tabs can be open, dolphin gestures, etc).

Answer (score 3):

I was using Dolphin HD for a while, but a lack of room on my internal storage forced me to swap to Dolphin Mini as it has a much smaller install size. I only use the browser for light browsing to a few regular sites, but I haven't found anything that I can't do in Dolphin Mini. In my experience you might not miss out on anything if you use Mini instead of HD.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Docs](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/65408/31824) is a noteworthy difference.

In short it seems that certain, small add-ons are hard-coded into the mini-version.

The goal is to keep it simple and small - but it lacks the full add-on-featurabilty of Dolphin.

This difference makes mini less flexible, but smaller.