# Disable Google docs in Dolphin Mini?

Tags: pdf, google-drive, dolphin-browser, browser-add-ons

[The answer to how to download PDFs](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/65354/31824) leads to a link describing that Dolphin mini uses google docs for opening pdf  and other [documents](http://dolphin.com/find-pdf-viewer-in-dolphin-browser-mini-v1-2-beta/).

From a programmers perspective this is a nice solution - the content is just passed to a web-service that displays the content on the browser.

But what if you do not like Google to read your pdfs at all?

What if you want to download a pdf, but the links to do so is generated so you can not press longer on it to start a download instead?

So as a follow up this question arises: How can I completely disable that google-docs-feature in Dolphin Mini?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how to answer this. Is there any reason why you prefer to use Dolphin Mini instead of Dolphin?

Comment: @geffchang I have both installed. I am using Dolphin without graphics as browser on low bandwith connections, while using mini as "secure" browser on high bandwith connectios. Less features, less attack vectors was my line of thought.